# React Native TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined, js engine: hermes

Tags: react-native, metro-bundler

[image]

I am working on a react-native project. I have been running the application on Android and iOS devices for the past 6 months. I haven't faced any problems till now. But suddenly today, while I am trying to run the application I am getting a compile error with the description. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined, js engine: hermes`. I tried to debug the issue and found that there is an issue while connecting to the remote debugger. But the strange thing here is even I haven't selected the remote debugging option from either of emulator or simulator.

So, I have enabled the remote debugging option from the emulator to get a quick fix. It is working fine. But why is it connected to the remote debugger even after the fresh installation? And the quick fix comes with its own issues. The application is functioning a bit lag and inconsistent. I suspect there is an issue with the metro bundler. I have removed the cache using `rm -rf /tmp/metro-*`  command, cleaned gradle using `./gradlew clean` command, and cleaned iOS build by deleting derived Data. But still, the issue persists.

Is there any other step am I missing here? If it is the issue with the metro bundler, is there any way to reset it completely? Please check the attached image for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this issue in my case is not with the metro bundler or its cache but with one of the third-party dependency named auth0-js(In your case it would be different). It is adding some global or window properties which are causing the above-mentioned issue. I have removed it and replaced with the library which is closed to react-native ecosystem which eventually resolved the issue.